# Correlation plot between two data frames in R (Correlation heatmap)

Tags: r, correlation

I have a dataset including several columns and I want to make a
correlation plot between x and y. X and Y include several variables.
For example in mtcars data from car library I want to have a
correlation plot between (mpg, cyl,  disp as X) and  (hp, drat, wt as
Y). How I can do it that R. Note: I want to have an output like "corrplot" output. The only difference is that I have different variables on x and y axes. Please see the attached file.

```
 library(car)
 data(mtcars)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do

```
x <- mtcars[, c('mpg', 'cyl', 'disp')]
y <- mtcars[, c('hp', 'drat', 'wt')]
cor_mat <- cor(y, x)
corrplot::corrplot(cor_mat)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks so much, just one question, how I can modify it in a way that  Colors reflect the Spearman r values (yellow for positive, blue for inverse correlations), and dot sizes reflect the P values?

Comment: @shoo I have no idea, sorry. Have you read somewhere that `corrplot` is capable to do so?